# ASP.NET : Multiple elements for an event doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, textbox

so, my problem is I have many textboxes created dynamicly from a database (x fields represents two textbox), I want to handle the same event Textchanged for all.

But when i put characters in a textbox, the event is launch for all textboxes who have this event.

Here is how I declare my textboxes:

```
            TextBox x = new TextBox();
            x.ID = "txtX" + reader.GetInt32(0);
            x.Text = "x";
            x.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);
            x.AutoPostBack = true;
            x.TextChanged += txtBoxTextChanged;

            TextBox y = new TextBox();
            y.ID = "txtY" + reader.GetInt32(0);
            y.Text = "y";
            y.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);
            y.AutoPostBack = true;
            y.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtBoxTextChanged);
```

And here is my event txtBox :

```
protected void txtBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox txt = (sender as TextBox);

            Response.Write("<script>alert(\""+ txt.ID +" a pour valeur : "+ txt.Text +"\");</script>");
        }
```

So, how can I find the control which has triggered the event ?

Thank for you help

Comment: So what is the exact issue here ???

Comment: _"the event is launched for all textboxes who have this event"_ - nope. Please describe exactly what happens.

Comment: How can I find which control has triggered the event ?

Comment: give txtBoxTextChanged event for all textboxes you have.

Comment: I can't, those textboxes are dynamicly created, and I want to handle the same event for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

when I created my textboxes, I put a text 'X' or 'Y'. And when the event triggered, all textboxes have a text, this is why it doesn't work first time, but after, it works.

Thanks everybody for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the event call is the sender. So there you have the control that caused the event.

Comment: I know but first time, the event triggered all textboxes. Second time, it triggered the true textbox. And I don't understand why ...

Answer (score 0):

May be you can add a name attribute to each of your text boxes like

```
 TextBox x = new TextBox();
 x.Name = "t1";
```

and inside the even handler you can check for that name,which will allow you to identify which text box fired the event.

```
TextBox txt = (sender as TextBox);
var name = txt.Name;
```

Comment: I'm not on a win project, but asp.net project, so I don't have the property "Name".

Comment: then you can check with the Id rite?

Comment: Yes, I can. But I don't think it's the best way to do what I want ... Because I can add dynamiccly other textbox, so I can't check all ...